# How about doing away with rep on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, meta

I notice a lot of people are marking their MSO questions/suggestions as community wiki, which I think is a good thing.  Since this site will be mostly discussion, opinion and feature suggestions, does rep make sense?

As far as the moderator powers that come with increased rep, couldn't those instead come after a certain level of contribution and time as an active member?  As your time as an active member and number of questions and answers increases, so do your powers as a moderator?

Comment: MSO started out without reputation, and it was deemed desirable afterward.  Someone's got to cleanup/moderate/retag/etc the content....and rep/badges are the path to many of those powers.

Comment: Did it really start with no rep? There was a period of a few hours that it was live before I woke up, but it had rep when I started using it. When I emailed Jeff with the list of changes that would make this site more discussion-oriented, I intentionally omitted removing rep because I thought it was still relevant and important to have.

Comment: Awesome! A meta question about the meta site.

Comment: @Stu: so perhaps at hard cap at 10K then?

Answer (score 9):

I believe the issue with doing this is there are still tasks that need to be done, like closing questions, retagging, editting, etc. And these require the reputation system to determine who can perform the tasks. Additionally, everything that is valid here would be at best Community-Wiki on SO, so perhaps its the Community-Wiki that doesn't belong?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it's *community wiki* that doesn't really make sense anymore since pretty much everything here will be subjective discussion and opinions.

Rep is Rep. It's mostly just for fun on MetaSO, except for unlocking various moderator abilities, which so far don't seem to be needed as much since so much more seems permissible here.

Comment: It's mostly just for fun on SO too...

Comment: Yeah, once you break 10k! ;)

Comment: It is only "fun" for some until they get downvoted. Then their whole world crashes to a halt and justice is begged for.

Answer (score 5):

It should be a badge of shame to have a higher meta-reputation than regular reputation. ;-)

Comment: Lining up for that badge right now.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you change the rules only for meta?

It seems more trouble than it's worth

Answer (score 2):

You need rep to be able to do stuff - re-tag, edit, close etc. and those functions will still be needed over here. Without rep being awarded here there are only two choices:

1. Only appointed admins can have these rights.
2. Use some function of your rep from SO/SF to determine who has those rights.

Comment: I'm in favor of using your average rep between the two sites as your rep for metaSO.

Comment: @jinguy - I wasn't really concerned with the exact mechanism just that you'd have to get the rep from somewhere. However, your idea is good so I've updated the point. BTW "/" wasn't meant to be a division sign ;)

Answer (score 2):

As a somewhat new SO user (at least I became more active in the last week after having the account for 10 months) I feel that rep on SO / SF / SU should cary over to MSO. From what I understand the reason for not having the same rep on all sites is that you could be very knowledgable in let's say a programming language (SO) but not for that reason very good at server maintenance (SF).

But if you are an active user on any of the non meta sites you should be considered allowed to have an opinion (up/down vote) about the meta parts of the sites. So once you've earned rep on one of the sites (by answering questions and behaving like a nice person) you should get that rep here as well.

At least that's my opinion.

Comment: If you've been active on the main sites, with over 200 rep you can get a bump of 100 on Meta when you associate your accounts.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have some dim memory of Jeff talking about that on one of the podcasts. Well, in that case it's all ok.

But if I gain rep on SO now that I have my meta account I guess I'll stay at 1 here.

Answer (score 0):

The community needs to have a voice and guiding influence on what is and isn't acceptable, and close votes are it's primary method.

And administrative tasks like editing and retagging are best spread over many people.